# very simple main where I am stuck adding two numbers

Tags: java, sum

I just want to write a program that adds two numbers so I wrote this

```
public class Mainclass {

public static void main(String[] args) {

        addTwoNumbers(5, 3);
        }

    public static int addTwoNumbers(int a, int b){

        int c;
        c = a + b;
        return c;}}
```

What is my problem?

I know in java it excepts always a main and I think that is the point at which the program executes so I wrote the other function above it so it can read from that function.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: `What is my problem?` - I'm wondering that too.

Comment: You have successfully written a program that adds two integers, 5 and 3.

Comment: What's is the problem ? Can you explain a bit more?

Answer (score -1):

That actually works. You are just not seeing it because you are not printing anything.
You should use `System.out.println(addTwoNumbers(5,3));`

Also for future reference, please use proper indentation.